# Как вывести в под меню родителя?

Tags: wordpress

Возник такой вопрос. Сделал меню вот код:

```
<?php if( $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items('Меню') ) { 
                $menu_list = ''; $current_class = ''; 
                foreach ( (array)$menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
                    if($menu_item->url == 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] || ($menu_item->url == site_url().'/' && substr_count(get_permalink(), 'p=') != 0 )){$current_class = 'active';
                    } else {
                        $current_class = '';
                    } if($menu_items[$key+1]->menu_item_parent != 0 && $menu_items[$key]->menu_item_parent == 0){
                        if($menu_items[$key]->menu_item_parent == 0){
                            $link_class = 'hover-li';
                        }else{
                            $link_class = '';
                        } 
                    $menu_list .= '<li class="dropdown '.$current_class.'"><a class="dropdown-toggle tut" href="'.$menu_item->url.'">'.$menu_item->title.'<b class="mtm-bullet"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu">';
                }else{
                    $menu_list .= '<li class="'.$current_class.'"><a  href="'.$menu_item->url.'">'.$menu_item->title.'<b class="mtm-bullet"></b></a></li>'; 
                        if($menu_items[$key+1]->menu_item_parent == 0 && $menu_items[$key]->menu_item_parent != 0){
                            $menu_list .= '<div class="close-sub"><img src="https://www.endocrinolog.by/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/icons8-strelka-100.png" alt /></div></ul></li>';
                        }
                    }
                } echo $menu_list; } ?>
```

Он мне выводит вот в таком формате:
Родитель 1
Родитель 2
--Дочерний 1
--Дочерний 2
Родитель 3
А как сделать чтобы я мог вывести так:
Родитель 1
Родитель 2
--Родитель 2
--Дочерний 1
--Дочерний 2
Родитель 3